# How to get the definition for 'Module' in TypeScript inside Jasmine Unit Test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So, this is really silly. But it is impossible to google for because the module that is undefined is literally `module`. I got rid of all the other TS errors in my unit tests except this last one:

> main/components/login/loginController.Spec.ts(12,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

Some have said, "just include angular-mocks.js" but I have done this and it eliminated some other errors, but not this one.

Here's my references:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/d3/d3.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
```

And here's a simple test illustrating the problem.

```
describe('Login Controller Spec', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      // uh oh
      module('App');
      inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = _$controller_;
        navCtrl = controller('loginController', { $scope: scope});
      });

    });

    it('should call init', function(){
         //...
    });
  });
```

Any other libs I should get definitions for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with

```
angular.mock.module('App');
```

since the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2517) is

```
  window.module = angular.mock.module = function() {
    var moduleFns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return isSpecRunning() ? workFn() : workFn;
    /////////////////////
    function workFn() {
      if (currentSpec.$injector) {
        throw new Error('Injector already created, can not register a module!');
      } else {
        var fn, modules = currentSpec.$modules || (currentSpec.$modules = []);
        angular.forEach(moduleFns, function(module) {
          if (angular.isObject(module) && !angular.isArray(module)) {
            fn = function($provide) {
              angular.forEach(module, function(value, key) {
                $provide.value(key, value);
              });
            };
          } else {
            fn = module;
          }
          if (currentSpec.$providerInjector) {
            currentSpec.$providerInjector.invoke(fn);
          } else {
            modules.push(fn);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

An alternative may be

```
window['module']('App'); // and maybe also window.module('App');
```

Comment: oh nice, I had always shorthanded it as module (from window) before, just assuming everything was bootstrapped for me. It's odd that adding the mocksTSD defined some other objects on window for me (as far as typescript compiler is concerned). Could have been another TSD though, going through many of them at once.

Comment: The source code is from `angular-mocks.js`, not from TypeScript definition files. It's just that `module` is a keyword in TypeScript and unfortunately it's also a name of a function in angular-mocks. However, angular-mocks define the function in `window` object and in `angular.mock` object (i.e. `window.module = angular.mock.module = function() {`) so you can just use the second object and you are good.